# problem to find open subset that contains sphere for wedge of two spheres.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I want to use van kampen theorem to show that the fundamental group of wedge union of two spheres is zero,I know that I must choose $U$ and $V$ which they are open and its union is the whole space.I know that I can't take $U$ and $V$ as two spheres but I can take open set containing one whole sphere,in that case they are open,the intersection is one point,and the union is whole space and every thing will be done,but I don't know what is that open subset which contains one whole sphere.

this problem is almost done,please help me to make it complete.thank you very much.

Comment: Take it the both open sets to be the wedge of two spheres minus a point in one of these spheres (this point can't be the gluing point, try the other pole).

Comment: in that case the intersection won't be a point,am I right or I am missing something?

Comment: the intersection is homotopy equivalence to a point,is it true?

Comment: Yes, because a spehre (any dimension) minus a point is homotopic to a point, do you remember $\mathbb{S^n}-\{p\}\equiv \mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: yes,I remember,can you explain to me how the wedge of two spheres minus one point is open?

Comment: Remember that the open subsets of the wedge are just those that come from an open set in the disjoint union of two spheres before they're glued together.

Comment: so when I remove one point from a sphere and consider the disjoint union of it with one complete sphere,result is open for disjoint union of two spheres which is open for wedge of two spheres?if I am right can you explain a little more?thank you very much.

Comment: You think open subset, but subset of what? Every set you put a point away becomes open!!

Comment: this point that I remove is not gluing point,I have a little problem with this:how it can be open when a sphere that is ''closed'' is attached at gluing point to a another sphere with one point removed?

Comment: Look, you have a set, $\mathbb{S}^2\vee \mathbb{S}^2$, but it should be any topological space. You pick any point $p$ in this set, and you put him away. Then you got $\mathbb{S}^2 \vee \mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \lbrace p \rbrace$. Is it clear it is open? It's the complement of a single point!!!

Comment: yes,I got it now,I know that I stuck on it,but I must understood it well,thank you for your explanation.